# What are the steps of preprocessing anonymized data for predictive analysis?

Tags: data-mining

Suppose we have a large dataset of anonymized data. Dataset consist if certain number of variables and observations. All we can learn about data is a type(numeric, char, date, etc.) of variable. We can do it by looking to data manually.
What are the best practise steps of pre-proccessing dataset for the further analysis?

Just for instance, let this data set be just one table, so we don't need to check any relations between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing#Data_quality) gives the complete set of validations currently in practice. Still, to start with:

- ***wherever possible, have your data written in such a way that you can parse it as fast and as easily as possible, using your preferred programming language's methods/constructors;***
- *you can verify if all the data types match correctly - like int fields do not contain string data etc;*
- *you can verify that your values are in acceptable range;*
- *check if a non-nullable field has null values;*
- *check if dates are in expected ranges;*
- *check if data follows correct **set-membership** constraints wherever applicable;*
- *if you have pattern following data like phone numbers, make sure they are in (XXX) XXX-XXXX design, if you prefer them that way;*
- *are the zip codes at correct accuracy level (in US you may have 5 or 9 digits of accuracy);*
- *if your data is time-series, is it complete (i.e. you have values for all dates)?*
- *is there any unwanted duplication?*

Hope this is good enough to get you started...

Comment: probably I need to update question, in order to clarify. Please see update.

Comment: @angubenko: I can't see any update to your question.

Comment: sorry I was typing it

Comment: @angubenko: Here is a link that you might find useful: https://www.coursera.org/course/getdata?utm_medium=email&utm_source=recommendations&utm_campaign=recommendationsEmail~recs_email_2015_09_27

Comment: @angubenko: Happy to help. :)